# Significato di "dare sulla voce" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Alto com’eri, mi proibivi l’orizzonte; io pedalavo e tu mi guidavi. Pedalavo piano, appena da mantenere l’equilibrio, per evitarti le scosse. A ruota libera infilammo via Tomacelli ove il traffico divenne più intenso, ti divertivi a scampanellare, a **dare sulla voce** ai passanti; mi chiedevi il nome delle strade, le notizie dell’anno trascorso, dicevi: «Mi sembra di entrare in un nuovo mondo».

Quello che va in bicicletta con l'autore è suo fratello.

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "dare sulla voce" che appare in questo passaggio. Nel [dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/V/voce.shtml) ho trovato che significa

> Zittire una persona, metterla a tacere di solito muovendole riproveri.

Tuttavia, non sono sicura che questo sia il senso nel brano sopra citato: il fratello di Vasco Pratolini faceva zittire i passanti riproverandoli dalla bicicletta? Per questa ragione vi chiedo: questo modo di dire può avere un altro significato?

Comment: @Gio: Puoi ripristinare la tua risposta? Andava benissimo e c'erano due esempi utili. Mi sono solo permesso di esprimere una mia opinione su una tua opinione.

Comment: @Gio: Sono d'accordo con DaG.

Comment: @DaG - in realtà il senso della mia risposta riguardava il  fatto che l’espressione fosse poco nota e quindi si dovesse usare con cautela. Ma visto che mi sono sbagliato non ha molto senso ripristinarla. Sarebbe giusto un doppione dell’altra risposta a questo punto.

Comment: @Gio: Non credo fosse esattamente un doppione: riportava la definizione di un altro dizionario e aveva quei due esempi di  uso che mi sembravano utili. In questo sito si ha la tendenza a dare un'unica  risposta a molte domande, ma io invece trovo sempre interessante avere parecchie risposte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anche il Garzanti indica come significato di ***[dare sulla voce](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=voce)***

> dare sulla voce a qualcuno: rimproverarlo, zittirlo, contraddirlo
>   vivacemente

come tu hai trovato su Hoepli.

La scena è quella di due fratelli che girano per la città facendo baccano e divertendosi ad apostrofare i passanti senza una ragione precisa, giusto per distrarsi dai problemi.

Answer (score 1):

Anche Treccani definisce ***[dare sulla voce a qualcuno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/voce/)*** come:

> contraddirlo, riprenderlo vivacemente.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dare%20sulla%20voce&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdare%20sulla%20voce%3B%2Cc0)  mostra che l'espressione è in uso da circa la metà del 1800, 
e compare ad esempio nel  seguente Dizionario della Lingua italiana compilato dagli Accademici Della Crusca,  del 1836:

[Dare sulla voce](https://books.google.it/books?id=WG91asA3WmoC&pg=PA932&dq=%22dare%20sulla%20voce%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiujJTT697ZAhXESBQKHbC2DeIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22dare%20sulla%20voce%22&f=false):

> Interrompere l'altrui discorso, Opporgli, Farlo tacere.

Un esempio più recente da [MM Rossa](https://books.google.it/books?id=aFxlAAAAMAAJ&q=%22dare%20sulla%20voce%22&dq=%22dare%20sulla%20voce%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq_Zfj7t7ZAhWDvRQKHaRuBGYQ6AEIQDAG) di Ferruccio Parazzoli,  del 2003:

> - O, almeno, non siamo in grado di vederli. O, forse, agiscono proprio quando noi non li vediamo. "Pensaci tu, allora" direbbe il solito moralista pronto a dare sulla voce.

Comment: Penso che i due esempi di uso erano anche interessanti.